# Quantum Coherences of a Subsystem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I am reading some stuff on quantum mechanics and have seen references to a subsystem B (where A and B are both subsystems in the system) which has quantum coherences which can be selected.  I was wondering if I could clarify what this terminology really means as there is a difference in meaning between 'decoherence', 'coherence' and 'coherent state' and I was wondering if I could clarify what is meant by a subsystem having particular 'coherences'.

EDIT:
from a paper 'On the role of complex phases in the quantum statistics of weak measurements' by H. F. Hofmann:

''As early as 1995, Steinberg pointed out that weak measurements provide a natural deﬁnition of conditional probabilities in quantum mechanics. However, the mathematically consistent deﬁnition of such weak conditional probabilities results in complex numbers originating from the quantum coherences of the initial and ﬁnal states''.

Also elsewhere in correspondence with a physicist working in quantum information, they referred to 'a mechanism by which a measurement in A determines quantum coherences in B', where A, B are subsystems of a larger system.

I am simply unsure what it means to refer to 'quantum coherences' in this way in the plural form in this context and was wondering if someone could clarify the meaning for me.

Comment: Sources? Links?

Comment: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/13/10/103009/pdf

Comment: In the introduction to this paper the author refers to 'quantum coherences of the initial and final states', I am just not entirely sure is meant when someone refers to quantum coherences in the plural form in this way.

Comment: @Tom could you copy the relevant parts of the text you linked into the question? That would make it easier to answer the question. Also, FYI, if you do not tag people in a comment they will not get notified of your answer, and most likely not see it at all

Comment: @glS I've added the reference to my post, let me know if you need any further information.